# Can I make clickable items from my GridView programmatically?

Tags: android, android-studio

In my app, I have an activity called `tasti.class`. When I press on the `button` "aggiungi tasti", it opens an `AlertDialog` where I can enter a name. Then when I press save, it will create a custom `CardView` in my `GridView` that is inside my `ScrollView` like you can see in the below screenshot.

[image]

Now, what I would like to know is if it is possible to make any of these created `CardViews` clickable. I want be able to change, when I click on one of them, the `Text` inside it.

Here is my `tasti.class` code:

```
public class tasti extends AppCompatActivity {

    RelativeLayout rellay_LOAD;
    GridLayout gridLayout;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tasti);

        rellay_LOAD = findViewById(R.id.rellay_LOAD);
        gridLayout = findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);

        rellay_LOAD.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                CustomAllert();

            }
        });
    }


    public void addLayout(String textViewText){
        View card = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.cardview, gridLayout, false);

        TextView textView = card.findViewById(R.id.btnName);

        textView.setText(textViewText);

        gridLayout.addView(card);
    }


    public void CustomAllert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(tasti.this);

        @SuppressLint("InflateParams") View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);

        final EditText bottone = mView.findViewById(R.id.etBottone);

        final EditText prezzo = mView.findViewById(R.id.etPrezzo);

        Button mLogin = mView.findViewById(R.id.btnADD);

        mBuilder.setView(mView);

        final AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();

        dialog.show();

        mLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (!bottone.getText().toString().isEmpty() && !prezzo.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {

                    Toast.makeText(tasti.this,
                            "Tasto aggiunto con successo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    addLayout(bottone.getText().toString());

                    dialog.dismiss();

                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(tasti.this,

                            "Non lasciare dei campi vuoti!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can do this? Is there a way to do it without `RecyclerView`?

Comment: Use gridLayout.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(tasti.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

Comment: Canno't resolve method setOnItemClickListener

Comment: Where are you put this

Comment: I'm putting it under onCreate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `clickListener` for the parent layout of that XML, which you have used in your `onCreateViewHolder` in your `RecyclerView`.

Say for example, if your `RecyclerView` item is like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/ll_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
// Your View Elements
</LinearLayout>
```

Add a listener in your `onBindViewHolder` like:

```
parentLayout.setOnClickListener({
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
cardView.setOnClickListener(v ->
{
    // update TextView text
});
```

This works if you don't mind using a Lambda statement. If you try using the above, then you might get a `lambda expressions not supported at this language level` error, which is easily fixed by updating Android Studio's Source Compatibility and Target Compatibility as shown [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html).

Since you create your `CardView` with XML, you can get it for programmatic use like this:

```
CardView cardView = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.yourCardViewId);
```

Comment: actually cardView is an xml layout file and not a cardView in my main layout will that work anyway?

Comment: @I.Mytyuk Well, you could try it and see if it works, if you want. This was just a way I found to make the CardView clickable without using RecyclerView, although, based on [the Android doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview), it is most recommended to use RecyclerView.